# Como faço para que quando a pessoa apertar em alguma determinada tecla seja aberta uma URL?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" a href="https://is.gd/DhDDsG">
<script>
var titulo = "- teste -"
var titulo = titulo + "          " 
i = "0"
var tmptitulo = "" 
var velocidade = "50"
const scrollTitulo = () => {
    if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
        return
    document.title = tmptitulo + titulo.charAt(i)
    tmptitulo = tmptitulo + titulo.charAt(i)
    i++
    if (i == titulo.length)
    {
        i = "0"
        tmptitulo = ""
    }
    setTimeout("scrollTitulo()", 35)
}
window.onload = scrollTitulo
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser usar apenas HTML é possível usando o `accesskey`, porém neste caso é preciso que aperte o `alt`, como `alt+s` seria:

```
<a href="https://google.com" rel="noopener noreferer" target="_blank" accesskey="s">
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Porém, se você quer apenas ao clicar `s` (ou qualquer outra tecla), sem o `alt`, deverá usar o JS, usando um simples EventListener. Você pode testar abaixo um exemplo, clique "s" e uma página será aberta.

```js
window.document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if (e.key != "s") {
    return
  }

  window.open("https://pt.stackoverflow.com", "_self");
})
```

O [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/keydown) será acionado sempre que uma tecla for pressionada. Então se o `key` for igual à `s`  ele irá abrir a página.